# How to fork in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, exec, fork

Hi i have a school project where I need to create a command line using an exec through a child process. i am scripting in bash.

here is my pseudocode:

```
while true; do
read -p "Please type your Linux command. Type q to quit." lnxcmd
case $lnxcmd in
 ([Qq]*) exit;
esac

CREATE FORK
FIND CHILD PROCESS
IN CHILD PROCESS- 
  tokenize into array A, split at " "
  get size of array in n
  aggregate everything from 1 .. n as variable B
  exec A[0], B
display result, and kill child process
```

and the loop goes on until q has been pressed. since i am not using c, i cant create a pid_t variable and assign it to fork() and get to the child process like that.

how can i get to the child process using bash commands? also, what is the proper syntax of exec for bash commands?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you fork/exec a child simply by running a command. eg `ls` forks a child and execs a copy of `ls`. To get the pid, run it in the background: `ls& pid=$!` – William Pursell

You can put your main job in a function, run that in the background, and `$!` expands to the PID. (Hmm ninja'd.) – 4ae1e1